# how to deploy multiple .sol files in the same scaffold eth project?

Tags: ethereum

how to create an ERC20 token to use in a separate staking contract on localhost? Is it included in the YourContract.sol file or do you deploy it in a separate .sol file?

Answer (score 1):

linking to scaffold eth docs here!

https://docs.scaffoldeth.io/scaffold-eth/toolkit/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/adding-a-new-contract

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).